# ¿Cómo agregar datos en un data frame utilizando condicionales?

Tags: r

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Lo que sucede es que tengo una base de datos amplia sobre transacciones que hicieron los clientes de una entidad financiera durante un mes, por lo que hay usuarios que aparecen repetidos en dicha base datos puesto que han realizado más de una transacción en el mes. Hay una columna que se llama <>" en la cual hay espacios que deseo llenar con datos. En total son tres segmentos: "Pensionado", "Independiente", "Empleado". Lo que quiero es llenar esos espacios con cada uno de los tres segmentos, pero teniendo en cuenta el documento de la persona. Es decir, colocar "Pensionado" en los espacios vacíos si el número de documento de la personas es xxxxxxxx, colocar pensionado "Independiente" en los espacios vacíos de la persona con número de documento xxxxx, y así sucesivamente hasta llenar todos los campos de la columna <>.

¿Esto se puede hacer? ¿Si es así, cómo se haría? Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido Maicol25 a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Por favor, añade un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y ejemplo de lo que esperas, también es importante agregar lo que hubieras intentado hacer hasta ahora. Saludos.